# How to use lambda expression in kotlin android with classes that has two or more callback methods

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin, callback

Let's make a scenario we have onClickListener() in java

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}});
```

we can use lambda expressions in kotlin to make it easier

```
 view.setOnClickListener({ view -> toast("Click")})
```

what if we have a class or interface with two callbacks or more,
like this one:-

```
Service.MakeApiCall(new OnCallListener() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(View v) {
    //some code
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(String x){
    //some code
  }
});
```

How to use Lambda expression in this situation like the OnClickListener Example

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas can be applied only for functional interfaces. Use object instead

```
val listener = object : OnCallListener() {
        override fun onSuccess(v: View) {
            //some code
        }

        override fun onError(x: String){
            //some code
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Lambda expressions are only a single method.

There is a workaround. You may create your own extension function that takes two lambdas:

```
fun Service.MakeApiCall(success: (View) -> Unit, 
                        error: (String) -> Unit) {
     MakeApiCall(object: OnCallListener {
        override fun onSuccess(v: View) {
            success(v)
        }

        override fun onError(x: String) {
            error(x)
        }
    })
}
```

The API you try to mimic looks similar to the Observer pattern. Probably, Kotlin Coroutines will help 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html

Comment: You need to fix the syntax for the anonymous class.